# Cell Reference in Google Sheets' Query is unsuccessful

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When creating a query in Google Sheets, I'm finding that hardcoding is working fine but using several references isn't working correctly.

Cell `A2 = 0.75` (from a formula `=(mround(Estimator!$C$4/57.2958,0.25))`, type = number)

Cell `B2 = 0.9` (from a formula `=(mround(Estimator!$C$5+100,0.1)-100)` type = number)

Specifically, the query below works:

```
=query(Time_Data, "SELECT N, O, P WHERE A="0.75" AND B="0.9)
```

And the query below works:

```
=query(Time_Data, "SELECT N, O, P WHERE A="&$A$2&" AND B="0.9)
```

But this query does not work:

```
=query(Time_Data, "SELECT N, O, P WHERE A="&0.75&" AND B="&$B$2)
```

And most importantly, this query does not work:

```
=query(Time_Data, "SELECT N, O, P WHERE A="&$A$2&" AND B="&$B$2)
```

Any suggestions about how to get this reference to work?

Comment: @jpv See below (there's no great format in StackOverflow)

Apple Bob Carrot Delta Epsilon Frank George Harriet Integer Juliet Kayak Lemon Marcus Nomad Olliver Penelope
0 0.3 0.9 -0.8 -0.6 -0.3 0 -0.8 -0.9 0 -0.6 0.6 0.2 0 0 0.95
0 0.3 0.9 -0.8 -0.4 -0.3 0 -0.8 -0.9 0 -0.4 0.6 0.4 0 0 0.97
0 0.3 0.9 -0.8 -0.2 -0.3 0 -0.8 -0.9 0 -0.2 0.6 0.6 0 0 1.09
0 0.3 0.9 -0.8 0 -0.3 0 -0.8 -0.9 0 0 0.6 0.8 0 0 1.16
0 0.3 0.9 -0.6 -0.6 -0.3 0 -0.6 -0.9 0 -0.6 0.6 0 0 0 0.92
0 0.3 0.9 -0.6 -0.4 -0.3 0 -0.6 -0.9 0 -0.4 0.6 0.2 0 0 0.9
0 0.3 0.9 -0.6 -0.2 -0.3 0 -0.6 -0.9 0 -0.2 0.6 0.4 0 0 0.96

Comment: Hi, you can share your spreadsheet with editing rights and drop the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called google support and they advised as follows: the formula in cell B2 was edited from

```
=(mround(Estimator!$C$5+100,0.1)-100)
```

to

```
=Value((mround(Estimator!$C$5+100,0.1)-100))
```

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we could see your data. But maybe try FILTER() and see if that works?

```
=FILTER(N:P, A:A=A2, B:B=B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct syntax:

```
=QUERY(Time_Data; "SELECT N, O, P WHERE A matches'"&$A$2&"' AND B matches '"&$B$2&"'")
```

and if by any chance it wouldn't work try:

```
=QUERY(Time_Data; "SELECT N, O, P WHERE A matches '"&INDIRECT("A2")&"' 
                                    AND B matches '"&INDIRECT("B2")&"'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  Unfortunately, neither seemed to work.

Comment: @soytsauce try now